# Conductor with StackPanel/LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

I just discovered Caliburn-Micro for WP8.

I'm trying to have multiple Views on a single page and found out that Conductor can help with this. However it seems that only Pivot/Panorama items are conducted by Conductor. I'm trying to layout general items like StackPanels, LongListSelector etc.

Can the Conductor conduct Items other than items of the Pivot or the Panorama?

Answer (score 1):

The `Conductor` from Caliburn.Micro is only intended to be used with Pivot and Panorama for the case where you have different ViewModels+Views on different "tabs".

For ListBox and maybe also LongListSelector there is and interesting convention you can use. Suppose in your list you have objects of type A and B. Then if you do not define any datatemplate and AView and BView exists, they will be used for as datatemplates.

Comment: Well I was hoping to 'Compose' largers views with smaller seperate views and each viewModel will handle it's own lifecycle.

Edit: Like a Master StackPanel containing child StackPanels which are bound to different Caliburn.Micro ViewModels.

Comment: not possible, one "screen" should be one viewmodel.

Comment: Sigh... need to find another way to do it then.

Thanks for the help.